# I manually delated a Trait file, now I get "Trait 'App\Http\Controllers\CommonTrait' not found". How do I fix this?

Tags: php, laravel-8

After manually deleting a Trait file that was no longer needed by the compiler I see that the compiler is looking in the Controller folder instead of the Traits folder.
I have tried `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan clear-compiled`,  `php artisan /clear-cache` and `php artisan optimize`. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem is to **make sure that nothing in your code is using the trait**. I found a controller that was still using the trait. Big newbie mistake. Maybe it's time for this old sea-dog to ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> After manually deleting a Trait file that was no longer needed by the compiler I see that the compiler is looking in the Controller folder instead of the Traits folder.

I guess this means you *moved* the Trait file into another directory?

Since `composer` usually is [configured to use the `PSR-4` autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) this would require you to also change the namespace of the move Trait.

I.e. trying to load `App\Http\Controllers\CommonTrait` the autoloader is looking for the Trait in the `src/Http/Controllers/CommonTrait.php` file. If you moved that file to say `src/Http/Controllers/Traits/CommonTrait.php` you have to change the namespace of the Trait to

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Traits;
```

and import it for usage as

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Traits\CommonTrait;
```

Comment: I moved the file to the recycle bin but later restored it to Apps/Http/Traits. The compiler guy says that the last place he looked for CommonTrait was the Controllers folder. How can I let him know that he can find it in the Traits folder.

Comment: as described in the answer: update the namespace accordingly and import with `use App\Http\Traits\CommonTrait;`

Comment: I am not sure what folder you are referring to;

EventController :

use http\Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Event;
use App\Models\Memorys;
use App\Http\Traits\KeywordTrait;
use App\Http\Traits\MatchupTrait;
use App\Http\Traits\CommonTrait;
USE Illuminate\Support\Facades\LOG;
use App\Http\Livewire\ChangeEventEvent;
use app\Http\Controllers\CommentCotroller;
class EventController extends Controller
{
    use KeywordTrait;
    use MatchupTrait;
    use CommonTrait;